# Why in C does a warning line like mentioned in code below is taking next line's string and printing?

Tags: c, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    printf("a"+14);

    printf("tera kya hoga kalia \n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

//this code prints

Hello world!

a kalia

tera kya hoga kalia

//why is it taking next line's print data.

//Yes new to C!!!

Comment: Undefined behavior calculating pointer arithmetic beyond the bounds of the object. C11 draft standard n1570 *6.5.6 Additive operators 8 [...] If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.*

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
printf("a"+14);
```

is quivalent to:

```
char const* s1 = "a";
char const* s2 = s1 + 14;
printf(s2);
```

The expression `s1 + 14` evaluates to an invalid pointer. Given the value of `s1`, only `s1+0` and `s1+1` are valid pointers.

Since `s2` is an invalid pointer, the line

```
printf(s2);
```

is cause of undefined behavior.

In fact, given the value of `s1`, just the computation `s1+i` is undefined behavior for all `i < 0` and `i > 2`.

From EOF's comment:

> 6.5.6 Additive operators 8 [...] If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: The undefined behavior starts with the addition. You wouldn't need the `printf()` to have undefined behavior.